# Accessing a SQL database

Tags: android, sql

I'm not able to get a cursor after a query to the content provider

I've rearranged uri, rebuilt the table, old code that has been updated to androidx, I'm initiatialzing the table in the Provider:

```
uriMatcher.addURI(authority, path_name, #);

@Override
public boolean onCreate(){
table = new table_name(context);
}
```

No error messages I'm getting a null cursor returned.  I think it might have something to do with the URI but when debugging I'm not hitting the query method of the Content Provider.

Comment: Share the complete class

Comment: Yeah, we need a lot more information. There are several places where this could go wrong. Please provide a [mcve].